# Query to MySQL and output to file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a BIG database (MySQL) - its a list of emails.
My task is to get a list of emails with my parameters.
I realised it in this way: you get the list on your screen and can copy it, but when the list is big (more 10k lines) its hard to handle with it.

SO I want to see the result of My SELECT query in a text file.

But can't figure it out how to do that. Have only this idea:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
fwrite($new_file, $row['name'] . "\r\n");}
```

Is this Ok if you want to write 10-30 thousands lines in one loop? Seems that the script wont work or will work very slow?
Any help appraciated

Comment: You can use the `INTO OUTFILE` option to the `SELECT` query to have the database write to a file directly.

Comment: For reference, see [SELECT ... INTO Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).

Comment: thank you! is it ok is the file will be big? Can I delete it after?